# Can git be used to download a GitHub release attachment?

Tags: git, download, github

I need a tool for downloading  GitHub release attachments at end-user machine. I only know that it has git installed.

Comment: No got can't download released binaries. Use `curl` or `wget`. But you need actual download link.